# RSA accumulator

Tags: accumulators

In the ZeroCoin paper, it uses a zk-proof from Camenisch's dynamic accumulator that shows a Pedersen commitment hides an element of an RSA accumulator (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45708-9_5.pdf). However, it looks like that the proof can also be used to prove that a subset of elements belong to the accumulator.

Now the question is: how does ZeroCoin prove that the Pedersen commitment hides a single element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element in the accumulator is a prime, between some chosen bounds. In this case, the Pedersen commitment

$$ c = g^Sh^r \pmod{p}$$

is chosen so that $c$ is prime. Then, all these values $c$, each representing a "coin", are accumulated into the RSA accumulator
$$u^{\prod {c_i}} \pmod{N}.$$

Whenever a coin is spent, the network checks that $c$ is indeed prime (meaning it cannot represent more than one accumulated value), and that its membership witness inside $A$ is valid. Note that this is done indirectly via the proof of knowledge you mentioned, but that proof of knowledge does indeed require $c$ to be prime. A proof is given in the [full version of the paper](https://cs.brown.edu/people/alysyans/papers/camlys02.pdf), Theorem 4.

Comment: I was reading the ZeroCoin paper. For the coin $c$, when it's spent, it looks like it is NOT disclosed to the public (that's why Camenisch's zk-proof is used). The check of $c$ is prime is performed when $c$ is added (created) and saved to blockchain, but not when it is spent (because $c$ is anonymous). So here, when it's spent, I could actually try to submit a proof for $c_1 * c_2$ and submit proof $c_1*c_2 = g^{S_1 + S_2} h^r'$. This looks like an attack?

Comment: As mentioned, Theorem 4 of the full paper says that a valid proof also proves that $c$ is prime. You are correct that $c$ is not disclosed, so as to not leak where the spent coin came from. That's why I wrote "that this is done indirectly"

Comment: Thanks. I'd assume it's the range proof that limits it to be a single prime?

Comment: It is more than just a range proof, it is a full proof of knowledge, but that is just one of the things it proves.